# Why this simple multithreading is not working.UI become unresponsive

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates, visual-studio-2005

I am new to multithreading.I googled some basic examples below is the code

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Me.BackgroundProcess)
Private Sub btnStartThread_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStartThread.Click
    t.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub StopButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
    t.Abort()
End Sub

Public Sub BackgroundProcess()
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BackgroundProcess))
    Else
        Do While True
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Iteration:" & i)
            i += 1
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

When I click on Start thread my UI becomes unresponsive.What would be the reason behind this.Below is the screenshot of UI
[image: Form1]

Comment: What is the point of this code?  It is not a good use of Threading.  All your code does is run on the UI.

Comment: @dbasnett I am studying multithreading.This is just a basic use.If you have any other links please share..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the "Background" thread checks to see if it is on the UI thread

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
```

and if not, it tells it to run on the UI thread.

```
Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BackgroundProcess))
```

If it is on the UI thread, it sits in a loop, blocking the UI thread, without pumping.

```
Do While True
```

To get this to work, one of the MANY ways to do it is like this:

```
Public Delegate Sub AddItemDelegate(ByVal item As Object)
Public Sub BackgroundProcess()
    Dim i As Integer = 1

    Do While True
        i += 1
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New AddItemDelegate(AddressOf AddItem), "Iteration:" & i)
         Else
            AddItem("Iteration:" & i)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
Private Sub AddItem(ByVal item As Object)
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
End Sub
```

Using a delegate is the prefered way.

Comment: ,Agreed but What should I do to make UI responsive

Comment: I would highly recommend using tasks if you can instead of threads.  Here is an excellent resource http://www.albahari.com/threading/ plus i did a dirt simple example on a blog post with more details http://wysnet.blogspot.com/2013/09/stack-overflow-question-tpl.html.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically hosing the UI thread with a massive amount of updates so it never gets a chance to respond to the user input. Change the loop to sleep for a small amount of time.

```
    Do While True
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Iteration:" & i)
        i += 1
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
```

Comment: I am getting warning near CurrentThread as 'Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.' What would be the reason

Comment: Sorry, I was just giving that as an example of what needs to be done; you need to find a way to stop consuming the entire UI thread in your loop. I edited the answer, see if that works.

Comment: k.this warning was because of Some setting.I changed those setting and it worked.Ref link is [Link]http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2860692b-eea6-4fe1-99ef-c53cc6a7f906/access-of-shared-member-constant-member-enum-member-or-nested-type-through-an-instance-qualifying

Comment: That warning was because "Sleep" is a "Shared" method of "CurrentThread".  You should use "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)" as now shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code the UI is unresponsive because the UI is receiving a vast amount of updates in a very short space of time, either stop the loop from being infinite :

```
        Do While True
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Iteration:" & i)
            If i > 10 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            i += 1
        Loop
```

Or add a wait timer after each loop to slow down the how often the UI is updated :

```
        Do While True
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Iteration:" & i)
            i += 1
            'Sleep for 1 second
            Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop
```

Also you should stop the code running on the UI thread as you are currently creating a thread to then run something on the UI thread, which seems un-needed to me.

i.e. change

```
Me.InvokeRequired
```

To be

```
ListBox1.InvokeRequired
```

And

```
Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BackgroundProcess))
```

To be

```
ListBox1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BackgroundProcess))
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback.But still my UI remains unresponsive.Stop button is not accepting any commands.I want to stop this thread by using stop button (t.abort).Can I break this infinite while loop by using t.abort() methos

Comment: You could try creating a class variable to use as the True statement and set it to false when the abort button is clicked. However if the loop is still infinite and without a sleep statement it will still cause the UI to freeze and the abort button won't be able to be clicked.